# Matlab: parfeval in combination with standalone executable (MCC)

Tags: matlab, mcc

i'm trying to create a matlab stand-alone executable containing parfeval statements and a waitbar. The following code runs perfectly within the matlab runtime. However, after compilation using mcc -m test_mcc.m I receive the following error:

error:

```
    Error using parallel.FevalFuture/fetchNext (line 243)
The function evaluation completed with an error.

Error in test_mcc (line 11)



Caused by:
    An error occurred interpreting the results of the function evaluation.

parallel:fevalqueue:FetchNextFutureErrored
```

code:

```
function test_mcc()
    N = 100;
    for idx = N:-1:1
        % Compute the rank of N magic squares
        F(idx) = parfeval(@rank,1,magic(idx));
    end
    % Build a waitbar to track progress
    h = waitbar(0,'Waiting for FevalFutures to complete...');
    results = zeros(1,N);
    for idx = 1:N
        [completedIdx,thisResult] = fetchNext(F);
        % store the result
        results(completedIdx) = thisResult;
        % update waitbar
        waitbar(idx/N,h,sprintf('Latest result: %d',thisResult));
    end
    delete(h)
end
```

any clues?

Comment: @AnderBiguri The syntax of `parfeval` is that the second input argument specifies the number of output arguments to be requested from the function passed as the first argument - so in this case, the `parfeval` call is entirely correct.

Comment: Hm, I tried that code in R2015b on WIN64, and it worked fine for me. What release of MATLAB/PCT are you using, what platform etc.?

Comment: I'm using R2014a on win64, apparently its a bug in R2014a. Mathworks provided me with a workaround. Thnxs

Answer (score 1):

Apparently its a bug in R2014a. Mathworks provided me with the following support:

> The error which you are receiving is caused by a bug in the Parallel
>   Computing Toolbox. "parfeval" requires certain components to be
>   compiled into the standalone application but these components by
>   default are not visible to the dependency analysis in MATLAB Compiler.
>   This bug has been fixed in release R2014b.
>
> To work around this issue in your current MATLAB release, add the
>   following line to your M-file and then recompile the standalone
>   application using "mcc":
>
> %#function parallel.internal.queue.evaluateRequest
>
> This line will allow the compiler to include the correct dependencies
>   into the standalone application.